# Bootstrap 4: have dropdown menu be the same width as search bar in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

See below for my HTML. If you click the search bar (top right), a dropdown menu appears. In the real code, this would be a menu of search results, of course. The problem is that I want the width of the dropdown box to be the same as the width of the search box.

I realize that there's one or more similar questions to this, but none of the answers there seemed to work for my specific scenario.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6e0448e881.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="searchbar"
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get">
                        <input name="q" id="qbox" data-toggle="dropdown" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>
                        <div id="search_results" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="qbox">
                            <div>a</div>
                            <div>b</div>
                            <div>c</div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>

                <li class="usericon">
                    <button class="btn" id="login_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Log in
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="login_dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        <style>
        .searchbar .dropdown-menu {
        left: initial;
        }
        </style>

        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: here's a picture of what the navbar looks like on my machine (Arch Linux, running Chrome). Please tell me if it looks different for you! 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCWlo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap 4 documentation, dropdown menus are best displayed with the `<div class="dropdown">` wrapped around input/button and `<div class="dropdown-menu">` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

```
<li class="searchbar">
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input name="q" id="qbox" data-toggle="dropdown" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>
        <div id="search_results" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="qbox">
           <div>a</div>
           <div>b</div>
           <div>c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</li>
```

This will ensure that the `dropdown-menu` will not have a width higher than the `input`. To then ensure that the `dropdown-menu` is always 100% of the `input` use,

```
div#search_results {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Screenshot short menu item]
 [image: Screenshot long menu item]

Comment: The search bar is definitely wider than 194px on my machine, which also seems to suggest that its width isn't fixed.

Comment: Okay, that is a little odd. I have tried across many screen resolutions and sizes. Could you have possibly changed something in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">` that we are not able to see?

Comment: I did notice that `<li class="searchbar"` is not closed. That shouldn't be cause of issue but you may want to add `>`

Comment: That stylesheet has nothing relating to the search bar other than the part which I included in the <style> tag in the HTML. The issue is reproducable without the stylesheet, I just forgot to remove that line when I made the minimal example (it doesn't actually reference anything from where I put this HTML file)

A quick check shows that the search bar is 224 pixels on my screen

Comment: I've added a link to a picture of what it looks like on my machine to the question.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had actually read that documentation page, but I must've missed that part somehow.